# Swift 5.7 protocol conform to Equatable

Tags: swift

How can I use `Equatable` with my protocol? I have tried 3 variants (None worked):

```
protocol Person: Equatable {
   var name: String { get }
}

struct A: Person {
   var name = "John"
}

struct B: Person {
   var name = "Josh"
}
```

***Variant A:***

```
class C {
   var persons: [Person] = [A(), B()]
}
```

got error: `//Use of protocol 'Person' as a type must be written 'any Person'`

***Variant B:***

```
class C {
   var persons: [any Person] = [A(), B()]
}
```

got error: `Type 'C' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'`

***Variant C:***

```
class C {
   var persons: [some Person] = [A(), B()]
}
```

got error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

Comment: Variant B is fine. There's no such error as you described when you compile that.

Comment: @FabrizioScarano I think they meant how to conform C to Equatable protocol given the second variant

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to implement a comparator if `name` defines the equality:

```
func == (lhs: any Person, rhs: any Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```